# Showing that the group is abelian

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\sigma = (123456)$ in $S_6$. And let $G = \{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \sigma^5\}$ be a group under operation from $S_6$.

Is $G$ abelian?

Workings:

A group is abelian if it is commutative.

$\sigma^2 = (123456)(123456) = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6) = (123456)(123456)$

$\sigma^3 = (123456)(123456)(123456) = (123456)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6) = (123456) = (123456)(123456)(123456)$

$\sigma^4 = (123456)(123456)(123456)(123456) = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6) = (123456)(123456)(123456)(123456)$

$\sigma^5 = (123456)(123456)(123456)(123456)(123456) = (123456) = (123456)(123456)(123456)(123456)(123456)$

I'm not sure if what I did is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The cyclic group generated by an element is always Abelian (since anything commutes with itself, so powers of an element commute with powers of the same element).

This is the cyclic group generated by $\sigma$ so it is abelian.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \in G$ (for any group $G$ and any element $a \in G$), then $<a>$ is cyclic, therefore abelian.